# Getting error on importing android.provider.CallLog

Tags: java, android

Doing:

```
import android.provider.CallLog;
```

I get the error: `The import android.provider.CallLog conflicts with a type defined in the same file`

Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.recognizer;

import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CallLog extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_log);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.call_log, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private String getCallDetails() {

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
            String callType = cursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
            }

            stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                    + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                    + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        cursor.close();
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

}
```

any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You named your class exactly like Callog,maybe thats the problem.